# Can we calculate superconducting properties of materials using first-principle?

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity

In his book [Condensed Matter in a Nutshell](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691140162/condensed-matter-in-a-nutshell), the late [Gerald D. Mahan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerald_Mahan) wrote that *The calculation of a crystal's superconducting properties is not yet possible (p. 5).* The book was published in 2010.

However, in 2013, Margine and Giustino published a paper titled [Anisotropic Migdal-Eliashberg theory using Wannier functions](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.87.024505) where they provided a way to calculate superconducting properties such as superconducting gap and critical temperature. Also, in 2023, there was a [virtual school on many-body calculations using EPW and BerkleyGW](https://epw2023.dryfta.com/index.php) where they had session on calculating superconducting properties. Moreover, google search reveals many such papers on calculating critical temperature using first-principle such as [this one (2016)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.03486) or [this one with Roeser–Huber Formalism (2022)](https://doi.org/10.3390/met12020337).

Then, in light of these new developments, can we say Mahan's comment is obsolete and nowadays we can indeed study superconductors using first-principle?

Comment: +1 but how accurate are those Tc predictions?

Comment: Is the question about conventional, phonon-mediated superconductivity or also unconventional SC? While the latter has alluded simple solutions as of now, conventional SC has had some development in recent years as you have pointed out (additional sources: [here](https://www-old.mpi-halle.mpg.de/mpi/publi/pdf/13015_17.pdf) and [this](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.125.057001) paper, as well as the special edition it appeared in)

Comment: @NikeDattani I am not sure about that and couldn't find any study on this but the preliminary results I am seeing from the above-mentioned virtual school tutorial, it seems promising. They found Tc to be 6.0K for FCC Pb where the experimental result is 7.2K.

Comment: @manju9 that's a good point but I didn't consider it while asking the question. I'll leave the question as it is so that people can answer for both cases. NikeDattani, forgot to mention, for MgB2, they found 50K in contrast to the experimental 39K.

Comment: Ilya Esterlis has some recent interesting papers on when Migdal-Elishberg theory is valid, and when it breaks down.

Comment: @Anyon From his [Google scholar profile](https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&user=Z4-D3-kAAAAJ), I see he has around 20 papers in just last 2 years. Could you specify which ones you are talking about?